# How can i fill a dropdown list before opening a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have a form that lists a bunch of links that open basic documents, ie. pdf, docs, etc.  On the right side those links I have a href link to open a jQuery dialog with details on each specific link, for example, name of link, option to upload a new updated document etc.  Now also in this dialog I would like to be able to have a dropdown list that holds a sort order, which would be a list of numbers 1,2,3,4,5 etc. so the user can reorder their links. What is the best way to fill the form textboxes, dropdown lists (most important) with needed data from the database and then open the jquery dialog.  I currently am using jquery ajax and webservice to fill the textboxes fine, but the dropdown list is getting filled after the browser is rendered.  I execute the ajax call with the jquery button click event when the user clicks on the href tag that lives on the right side of each link.  This doesnt allow me to grab the selectedvalue on postback on the save button click event to get the updated values and update the record.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function LoadDocumentSort(id, selectedSort) {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: baseUrl + 'webservices.asmx/GetSortCount',
    data: JSON.stringify({ articleID: articleid }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',

    success: function (data) {

        if (data.d != '') {

            $("#UIEditSort").empty();
            var sortCount = data.d;

            var listItems;
            listItems = "<option value=''></option>";
            for (var i = 1; i < sortCount + 1; i++) {


                if (selectedSort == i) {
                    listItems += "<option selected='true' value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
                    //$("#UIEditSort").append($("<option selected='true'><option />").val(i).text(i));
                }
                else {
                    //$("#UIEditSort").append($("<option><option />").val(i).text(i));
                    listItems += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";
                }
            };

            $("#UIEditSort").html(listItems);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: wow.... slow down. Paragraphs are good, and code is even better. Describe the specific problem you're having and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.  My issue is i need to get a dropdwon list loaded before the jquery dialog is opened.  Im using a jquery button click event to make a ajax call to populate textboxes and that works fine when my dialog opens.  On the success of that ajax call i call this function to try and load the dropdown list:

Comment: One suggestion I can make is that open the dialog box with message loading.... and hide the div containing the textbox and dropdown and call the AJAX call for the text box and on the success of the that call the drop down. Only after the success of the drop down ajax call .show the content of the text box and drop down.

Comment: Thanks you Devesh.  Can you provide an example or point me to a good example of opening a dialog box with message loading?  The logic makes sense but not sure what the message loading is.

Comment: @ches185 I have added the possible pseudo code in the Answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution make look like this pseudo code

```
      $('#link').on("click",function(event){
        $("#loadingDiv").html('Loading ....').show();
        $("#containerOfControls").hide();
        $("#dialogId").dialog('open');
    //Now make the first ajax call
    $.ajax({
     URL: '',
     success : function(result){
                //Populate the textbox and make another ajax call
                  $.ajax({
                  URL : '',
                   success : function(result){
                                //Populate the dropdown
                                  $("#loadingDiv").hide();
                                   $("#containerOfControls").show();

                              }
                         }}}});
```